# Quando e dove si è usato "ventana" come sinonimo di "finestra" in italiano?

Tags: word-usage

Sfogliando il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, mi è sembrato curioso trovare [questo lemma](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000751.jpg):

> **Ventana<sup>2</sup>**  sf. Finestra. 
>       *Linati*, 20-7:  Li  avrà  notati  laggiù,  sull'angolo  dell’Aquarida, appoggiati  braccia  conserte  al  parapetto  delle  ventane,  a  guar­dar nella contrada, all'ora dell'aperitivo. 
>       = Spagn. *ventana*, deriv. da *viento* (v. VENTO).

La citazione è tratta dal libro *A vento e sole* di Carlo Linati, pubblicato a Torino nel 1939.

Sono curiosa di sapere quando e dove si sia usata questa parola con questo significato in italiano.

Qualcuno di voi ne saprebbe qualcosa?

Comment: Hai provato a cercare il termine nei libri italiani su Google Books?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Ho cercato di farlo da Google Ngram Viewer (c'è un altro modo di farlo?), ma mi appaiono testi in spagnolo e alcuni dizionari sardi.

Comment: books.google.com, preferenze, imposta la lingua a italiano.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni:  Sì, ma le impostazioni di lingua credo facciano riferimento soltanto alla lingua in cui utilizzare i prodotti Google. Da Google Ngram Viewer posso scegliere il corpus italiano.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AGIUQGa

Comment: Grazie, @FedericoPoloni: ho visto che questo (scegliere documenti scritti solo in italiano) si può fare dalla "Ricerca Libri avanzata". Mi appaiono, però, gli stessi risultati di quando l'ho fatto da Google Ngram Viewer, cioè, testi in spagnolo e dizionari sardi.